# Exchange 2007: can I configure a different SMTP send connector per user?

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2007

I want to configure a separate SMTP send connector per user.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Exchange.  About the closest you can get is to use scoped connectors to limit routing of outbound email to the local site.

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/exchangesvrmigration/thread/b2c76623-b5ee-457b-9d43-283993075974

Comment: We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This may theoretically answer the question however, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are also 3rd party tools that allow this. Check out [MultiSendcon](http://www.servolutions.com/multisendcon.htm). It distributes emails to different smtp relays / smarthost according to the sender.